# High speed multiplexing for multiple I2C devices

Tags: i2c

I'm trying to connect 32 I²C "root of trust" NXP A71CH devices.

https://www.nxp.com/products/identification-security/authentication/plug-and-trust-the-fast-easy-way-to-deploy-secure-iot-connections:A71CH

I'm trying to multiplex 32 devices for that chip.

I'm looking for a very fast way of multiplexing those 32 devices, an idea or schematic or a design.

The only solution that I found is to use an FPGA.  Is there a clever solution with just normal embedded microcontrollers ?

One chip costs 50ms, If I want to do 1000 signing, it would cost 1000*50ms. What I want to achieve is to have 1000signing with just 50ms cost. Is there a way of that without using FPGAs ?! Only with discrete components

Comment: If you generalise the problem: you want to use many I2C devices. If addresses are selectable and/or you have enough I2C busses, you might be able to do it without additional hardware. Otherwise, there are I2C multiplexers - have you looked into that? FPGA solution is a bit confusing here; where did you find that?

Comment: These chips have one address pin, which means you need e.g. five PCA9546A four channel I²C mux to create 16 buses from one. E.g. Linux handles those muxes automagically and make the userspace see 16+4+1 buses.

Comment: @Janka I didn't understand, what does Linux do with that issue ?

Comment: Google-fu: i2c bus address multiplexer

Comment: @PeterSmith I2C bus multiplexers are too slow for that issue, switching 32 devices is too slow!

Comment: @Andre If that is too slow, it may be reasonable to set your speed expectations in the question.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat one signature takes 50ms, I'm looking for at least 500ms for switching 32devices

Comment: Considering that !2C is not particularly fast (400kHz is the maximum supported rate for the A71CH), what do you consider fast switching?

Comment: @PeterSmith Is it possible to use parallel Rasperry pi with MPI interface to solve that issue ? I don't mind a cost of less than 500$ or a solution under that price

Comment: The I2C bus will most likely not be blocked while the A71CH chip is doing its work. So you can use this time to give new work to other chips or collect the result from other chips. Therefore, the chips can work in parallel. Assuming it takes 3ms or less to assign work and collect the result from a chip, you should be able to keep all chips busy at all time and achieve a throughput of about 600 signings per second.

Comment: I gave Linux as an example how an OS handles the MUX control automatically so you don't need to care about the additional complication.

Comment: @Codo Thanks so much for your input. Would you please post an answer with more detailis.. like how would the chips work in parallel, how would the master do the work to these chips in parallel, how would I use the I2C multiplexer for that design scenario ?

Comment: @Janka Is it possible to do your design with rasperry pi ? can you post a detailed answer ?

Comment: Given you can run Linux on the Pi and it has an I²C, yes.

Comment: Hey, you are going to bill your customer, not I.

Comment: @Janka I would go for your solution, can you post an answer with the following questions? What software paradigm has to be used ? Producer consumer ? Which language do you recommend ? How would I collect the results, send the command ? should I use queues ?

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.